# Rspec, how to use multiple fixtures for geocoder gem to test near function

Tags: json, rspec, rails-geocoder

I just discovered the Geocoder gem and my question is related to how to test it's use through Rspec.
As I have seen here [How to test geocoder gem](http://davidtuite.com/posts/how-to-test-the-ruby-geocoder-gem)

I created a google_data.json to simulate the googlemaps response in order to no hit their API everytime and to not consume my daily request amount (moreover in this way test are really faster). My problem comes when I want to test a function like this one

```
def self.find_by_radius_from_location(location, radius=10)
  coords = Geocoder.coordinates(location)
  Garage.near(coords, radius, units: :km)
end
```

and here is my test (which works if I connect to gmaps api)

```
describe 'find_by_radius_from_location' do
let!(:garage_inside_radius) { FactoryGirl.create(:turin_garage) }
let!(:garage_outside_radius) { FactoryGirl.create(:rome_garage) }

  context 'given a city' do
    it 'should return one garage' do
      garages = Garage.find_by_radius_from_location('Torino', 10)
      garages.first.should eq(garage_inside_radius)
      raise garages.inspect
      ids = garages.collect { |g| g[:id] }
      ids.count.should be(1)
    end
  end
end
```

The garages coord are right (the test pass if I connect to gmaps) what is wrong is my json, because I receive 2 garages instead of 1. 
Here it is

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "Via Monginevro 162, Torino, Italy",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Via Monginevro 162",
      "short_name": "Via Monginevro 162",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Torino",
      "short_name": "Torino",
      "types": [ "city", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Italy",
      "short_name": "IT",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 45.0647,
        "lng": 7.63015
      }
    }
  }, {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "Via G. Ferraris 2/4, Roma, Italy",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "Via G. Ferraris 2/4",
      "short_name": "Via G. Ferraris 2/4",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Roma",
      "short_name": "Roma",
      "types": [ "city", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Italy",
      "short_name": "IT",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 41.8084,
        "lng": 12.3015
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

What's wrong with that? Is there any way to test my `find_by_radius_from_location` function ? I suppose I should receive only one Garage but I receive 2... Why?

**EDIT**

I have found a workaround but maybe there is a better way to achieve this.

```
let!(:garage_inside_radius) { FactoryGirl.create(:turin_garage) }
let!(:garage_outside_radius) { FactoryGirl.create(:rome_garage) }
let(:outside_coords) { { latitude: 41.8084, longitude: 12.3015 } }
before(:each) do
  garage_outside_radius.update_attributes(outside_coords)
end
```

Comment: The right way to test `find_by_radius_from_location` is to stub `Garage.near`. Is that your question, or are you asking why you're getting two garages?

Comment: Sorry, you are right my question is a little confused. Let me edit it!
By the way, I'm asking why I get 2 garages instead of one.